# Set of pairs of options that could be wrong/right

Tags: combinatorics, statistics, combinations

One has a list of n options out of which 2 are incorrect, and guesses can be made by picking a pair of options. After picking a pair as a guess, it is either valid, in which case both of the pair's options are incorrect, or not, in which case one or both are a correct option.

How would making a invalid guess change the probability of other pairs being valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $n(n-1)/2$ possible pairs of which $2(n-1)-1$ pairs are incorrect hence the probability to pick an incorrect pair is $(4(n-1)-2)/(n(n-1))$.

Will making an invalid guess you gain information on where is, at least one, of the incorrect options. Thus the probability of getting an incorrect pair decrease. You have now $n(n-1)/2-1$ possible pairs (all the pair minus the one you picked) and $2(n-1)-2$ incorrect ones. hence the probability is now $2(n-2)/(n(n-1)/2-1)$.

Comment: If a pair is invalid, could you assume that both options in the pair have a 0.33 chance of being incorrect, since there could be three combinations that are assumed invalid - Y/N, N/Y, Y/Y?

Comment: No because there is way more pairs with only one incorrect option and only one pair with both option incorrect. So the probability that both are incorrect is $1/\#(incorrect~pairs)=1/(2(n-1)-1)$